# How can I run Final Cut Pro on an 2011 MacBook Pro?

Tags: mac, final-cut-pro

I have an early 2011 MacBook Pro running high Sierra (the latest operating system supported) and I needed to get final cut pro. you can't natively download it from the App Store without an error. so I bought and downloaded it on my friends 2016 15 MacBook Pro running Catalina and put it on a usb drive to copy to my computer (I did the same thing with iMovie so I was confident that it would work) once I plugged it into my computer and copied it to my applications folded and tried to open it but when I did it said it required Mac OS 10.14.6 (my Mac can only support 10.13.6) I tried editing the info.plist file and it didn't work. I really need this software on my computer please help.

Answer (score 1):

VMWare Fusion 11.5 supports your hardware, your os and can virtualize the newer macOS. There is a free download so you can make sure it runs before you spend for a license.

- https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/fusion-evaluation.html

You do not need the pro version.

Comment: But the graphics in my Mac are not metal compatible

Comment: Gonna be slow, @joe until you upgrade your hardware. (Assuming you’re not up for re-implementing metal)

Comment: How would you re-implement metal?

Comment: I wouldn't @Joe - it would be a lot of engineering. For me it would make sense to spend my time doing other useful things and then buy an upgrade. But maybe other people have more smarts or time than me.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway the virtual machine is pretty cool